# dual booting with windows unallocated space, and how resize /home partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, gparted, resize

I am dual booting with windows 10. I just resized the windows partition and have unallocated space between it and my linux installation. I would like to add it to my /home partition without breaking the dual boot with windows and would really appreciate some help doing so.
*And I know I should have done the resizing before I installed linux :|

And can it be done form gparted in linux or doo I need to boot from live CD to do this?

[gparted partition overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PysZX.png)

Comment: [Easy to do.](https://www.howtogeek.com/116742/how-to-create-a-separate-home-partition-after-installing-ubuntu/). Skip the section on 'While Installing Ubuntu' as it's not relevant here..

Comment: While it can be done (move partitions, fix UUIDs and grub + whatever mistakes), it seems more work, then backup and reinstall. Also, there is no "gparted in linux".:~)

Comment: I partially agree with @mikewhatever that a reinstall would be easier and more reliable in this particular case. You don't have that much data. Back it up and reinstall. However, I'd recommend not partitioning your installation into a / and /home partitions on such a smallish HDD/SSD.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)